# Units and inputShape in TensorFlowJS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm new to TensorflowJS and ML. In the API Reference, the following code is [there](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.10.0/#sequential).

```
const model = tf.sequential();

// First layer must have an input shape defined.
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 32, inputShape: [50]}));

// Afterwards, TF.js does automatic shape inference.
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4}));

// Inspect the inferred shape of the model's output, which equals
// `[null, 4]`. The 1st dimension is the undetermined batch dimension; the
// 2nd is the output size of the model's last layer.
console.log(JSON.stringify(model.outputs[0].shape));
```

What I want to know about is,

What is`inputShape` ?

What is the automatic shape?

Since the `unit` referred to attributes of the data set, why `unit` set to 4 in `model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4}))` line. (the layer defined the `unit` as 32 in `model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 32, inputShape: [50]}))`) Since `sequential()`'s outputs of one layer are the inputs to the next layer, the aren't the units must be same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is `inputShape` ?

It's an array which contains the dimensions of the tensor, which is used as input when running the neural net.

> What is the automatic shape?

It just uses the output shape of the layer before. In this case `[32]` because the layer before is a dense layer with 32 units.

> Since the unit referred to attributes of the data set, why unit set to
>   4 in `model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4}))` line. (the layer defined
>   the unit as 32 in `model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 32, inputShape:
>   [50]})))` Since sequential()'s outputs of one layer are the inputs to
>   the next layer, the aren't the units must be same?

Unit defines the output shape of a dense layer. In this case the neural should have 4 outputs, so the last layer has to have 4 units. The output- and input-shape don't have to be the same, because the output of each neuron (the amount of which is the outputshape) is calculated based on all neurons(output) of the previous layer. (In case of a dense layer)

Answer (score -2):

I always prefer a working example. Here is about as easy an example as I can make.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.10.3"> </script> 

<input type="number" id="myAsk" value="5"><br> 
 
<input id="myButton123" type="button" value="Keras Layers Train and Test" onclick="{
       document.getElementById('myButton123').style.backgroundColor = 'red'                                                                              
                                                                                
    model = tf.sequential(); // no const so that it is a global variable 

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 10,  inputShape: [1] }) );  
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 10 }) );  
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units:  1 }) );  

   model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});

   // Generate some synthetic data for training.
   const xs = tf.tensor2d([[1], [2], [3], [4]], [4, 1]);
   const ys = tf.tensor2d([[1], [3], [5], [7]], [4, 1]);

                                                                  
  (async function () {   // inline async so we can use promises and await
                                                                                    
    for (let myLoop = 1; myLoop <= 100; myLoop++) {                                                                                 
        var myFit = await model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 10 });
        if (myLoop % 20 == 0){   
             await tf.nextFrame();   // This allows the GUI to update but only every 20 batches      
             document.getElementById('myDiv123').innerHTML  =  'Loss after Batch ' + myLoop + ' : ' + myFit.history.loss[0] +'<br><br>'                                                                           
        }
                                                                   
    }                                                                                    
                                                                                    
                                                                                 
    const myPredictArray = await  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([document.getElementById('myAsk').value.split(',')], [1, 1]))  
                                                                                    
    document.getElementById('myDiv123').innerHTML += 'Input '+document.getElementById('myAsk').value+', Output = ' + await myPredictArray.data() +'<br>'
    document.getElementById('myButton123').style.backgroundColor = 'lightgray'                                                                                
                                                                            
  })() // end the inline async funciton                                                                        
                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                       
}" style="background-color: red;">   

 
<input id="myButton123b" type="button" value="re-Test" onclick="{
   (async function () {                                                                
   const myPredictArray = await  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([document.getElementById('myAsk').value.split(',')], [1, 1]))  
                                                                                    
   document.getElementById('myDiv123').innerHTML = 'Input '+document.getElementById('myAsk').value+', Output = ' + await myPredictArray.data() +'<br>'
   })() // end the inline async funciton                                                                                     
                                                                                  
 }"><br><br>

<div id='myDiv123'>...</div><br>
```

Comment: You have to add disclosure when linking your own website, otherwise it could be considered spam. See [how not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: This is not a good answer. There is no explanation at all. This code was basically just copy-pasted from the TensorFlow.js website and with `inputShape: [1]` it's too simplified to actually be useful. :/

Comment: It is supposed to be a simplified answer so that users can see how inputShape works. It is a full working webpage without a compiler. Absolutely no examples on the Tensorflowjs site are this easy to run, since all the Tensorflowjs examples expect you to use a compiler of some sort. I made it completely from scratch. Yes it could have more comments, but it doesn't

Comment: Downvote. While this provides example code, it's not useful to me because it doesn't explain _what_ the example code is doing, or indeed _why_. If I wanted example code without an explanation, I could check the API reference.